# HCL Domino - How to insert current date in the target field in HEI (LEI) direct transfer activity?

Tags: lotus-domino, hcl-notes

I have an HEI (LEI) direct transfer activity which connects to SQL database and loads the Notes fields data into the SQL table. I have several field mappings. There is one field in the target table to which the activity should insert the current date whenever the activity runs. How do I achieve this ?

Comment: Can't you put an @Formula to execute in the global Data Transformation field ?